# python3 write excel has exception UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, exception, utf-8, xlsxwriter

I use python3 module `xlsxwriter` write a excel file, and I want give the file a name which contains chinese word. However it gives me an exception **UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 3-8: ordinal not in range(256)**
I want to know how to deal with it.

Comment: Show code that generates the error and the complete error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a 'u' before the file name to represent it as a unicode string.

```
u'filename_with_chinese_chars"
```